# Error at classpath when trying to run a Tapestry ApplicationServlet

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm trying a hello world tutorial about Tapestry. I'm trying to do everything the same way it's written in the official tutorial [enter link description here](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/quickstart/helloworld.html)

But every time I run the http://localhost:8080/HelloTapestry/app I get this error :

```
Aug 02, 2016 10:19:29 AM org.apache.tapestry.error.RequestExceptionReporterImpl reportRequestException
WARNING: Unable to process client request: Error at classpath:/org/apache/tapestry/components/Insert.jwc, line 34, column 28: Error adding property format to class org.apache.tapestry.components.Insert: Unable to add method void setFormat(java.text.Format) to class $Insert_1: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
org.apache.hivemind.ApplicationRuntimeException: Error at classpath:/org/apache/tapestry/components/Insert.jwc, line 34, column 28: Error adding property format to class org.apache.tapestry.components.Insert: Unable to add method void setFormat(java.text.Format) to class $Insert_1: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18 [classpath:/org/apache/tapestry/components/Insert.jwc, line 34, column 28]
```

I'm using dynamic web project with servlets 2.3, java compiler 1.7, tomcat 7.0 and Tapestry 4.1 (I tried 4.1.3 libs but it asked for logging lib, I tried servlets 3.0 it gave me the same class path error)

Any hint please?

Comment: Hi, I don't know about your problem, as I only have experience with Tapestry 5+, but if possible I advise you to use the newest version of Tapestry as version 4 is very old and you will not get a lot of support. Tutorial: http://tapestry.apache.org/getting-started.html